# Form Organization In a Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a new Rails app for a client and one of the requirements is to allow people to fill out service request forms. There are 10 request forms so far and they're all different. To implement this I was thinking of creating a separate Model, View and Controller for each one to keep everything simplistic and RESTful. I'm kind of worried though about having 10+ different MVCs and routes just for the forms. Is there potentially and better way to achieve this?

Also the data submitted just gets emailed. No saving to a database.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct to make them all separate resources, controllers, models, etc.

If possible, you can DRY the code that is similar among them. For example, if some of the forms have similar validations, or parameter filtering, or scopes, etc.

> I'm kind of worried though about having 10+ different MVCs and routes just for the forms

In my opinion, 10+ different MVCs are fine for 10+ different resources. You may be interested to read about "DAMP" coding. I personally recommend DRY underpinnings and DAMP resources.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning DAMP. I'll go look up more about that. I actually just found out from the client that they only need 6 forms now. :) So this will be simpler than I thought. Thanks for the help!